# I disabled real-time monitoring of Windows Defender, but a PowerShell script is still blocked

Tags: windows-10, security, powershell

I disabled real-time monitoring of Windows Defender by running the command in PowerShell as admin:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
```

But still can't execute script [Get-TSLsaSecret](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-TSLSASecret-9bf94965). When I try to run it I get:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ function Get-TSLsaSecret {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptContainedMaliciousContent
```

**EDIT1:**

I was able to run the script after switching Windows Defender real time protection off manually in Windows Settings. But its not clear why the command does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Defender dislikes `Get-TSLsaSecret` because this script accesses the
most secret part of Windows.

The LSA secrets are stored as
[LSA Private Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secmgmt/storing-private-data)
in the registry under key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets`.
For example, all information for accessing system services, including passwords,
are kept as plain-text under the subkeys named `_SC_<ServiceName>`.
User account information is also kept here.

The data can be hacked.
See for a forensic treatment the article of
[Use PowerShell to Decrypt LSA Secrets from the Registry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-decrypt-lsa-secrets-from-the-registry/).

Not surprisingly, access to this key is rigidly controlled and is impossible to
access even for administrators. Windows Defender will guard against any such
attempt, and when scanning the disk will even delete scripts that hack the LSA.

Conclusion: In order to use this script you will basically need to deactivate
Windows Defender. If you ever re-activate it, you may find that your script
was quarantined and will need to be allowed and restored.

Comment: Finally I started the script, but it shown me only user names, but not passwords. Is it possible to write script that shows the passwords?

Comment: Why is the script requires 32-bit mode?

Comment: See the article [Dumping Clear-Text Credentials](https://pentestlab.blog/tag/lsa/).

Comment: What about SAM file? Does it relate to these secrets?

Comment: See [article](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/blog/default.aspx?p=c2bacbe0-d4fc-4876-b6a3-1995d653f32a).